# Automated login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run python selenium and automate the login process.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime, date

currentDate = ("{:%Y%m%d}".format(datetime.now()))
usernameStr = 'email'
passwordStr = 'passoword'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://website.com/en/entry?' + 'date=' + currentDate)
delay = 3


loginButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-header"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
loginButton.click()
delay = 3 
Username = browser.find_element_by_name('Username or Email Address')
Username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('vm.submitLogin()')
nextButton.click()
```

Here is the html I'm trying to access

```
<span class="input-wrapper">
<input type="email" placeholder="Username or Email Address" 
autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" 
ng-model="vm.username" ng-pattern="/^[^<&quot;>]*$/" 
ng-required="true" did-disable-validate="
"ng-focus="vm.resetUsername()" 
class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern 
ng-touched" tabindex="0" 
required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"></span>
```

I've tried to access the html by name, css selector, xpath, but nothing seems to work. It's a login banner and not a standard html page so idk if that makes a difference or not.

oh ya here is there error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aj/Desktop/streakscraper/login.py", line 20, in <module>
    Username = browser.find_element_by_name('Username or Email Address')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 784, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"Username or Email Address"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)
```

Comment: isn't it inside an `iframe` ? Is the classname really `vm.submitLogin()` ?

Comment: Yes. Does that mean it's not possible to access the html elements from within the iframe?

Comment: @PedroLobito yes the html is exactly how it is on the web page

Comment: @PedroLobito I wonder how you conclude its all within a frame. I don't see any iFrame tag in the HTML DOM provided by OP :)

Comment: @PedroLobito how did you know it was inside an iframe? I'm noob so I'm trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @tin10 I didn't, pure intuition based on my white hairs of selenium. GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to the correct `iframe`, then try to match the `html`:

To change to a different `iframe` use:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name"))
```

or simply:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")
```

You can also access it by index:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0) # 1, 2, etc.. if you have multiple iframes
```

To switch back to the main content use:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: You're welcome @tin10, but I think your problem is deeper than this, pay attention to your code, you're trying to select elements by `name` when they don't have the attribute `name`, you may want to use a different type of selection, by `css`, `xpath`, `type`, `id` or any other attribute. Take a look at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Ya that's the resource I've been using I got it to work. Thanks so much for the iframe info I would've been stuck forever trying to figure that one out.